Angular Network Error 404 Not Found when trying to access lazy loaded page by link address
On the dev environment, if I try to access page by link, the page is module and loaded lazily, network returns 404 Not Found.
 {
    path: "",
    loadChildren: () => import('@modules/desired-module').then((module) =>   module.DesiredModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard, UserRolesGuard],
  }, 

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}


I added preloading strategy and it worked in such cases when I open another modules before. BUT, when I directly open the page it shows 404 error.
What can I do to access the link directly and data be fetched without errors?

please share all the routes, route you are navigating to
